# Pick up points from the map and store the coordinates in the database, but some points are not GPS coordinates

Tags: android, greendao, arcgis-runtime

The function is to select points from the map and store the co-ordinates of the points in the database.

This is normal:

[image]

But there are some special cases, I don't know what caused it:

[image]

I don't know why this happened, please help me. Thanks.

The code of Screen coordinates converted to GPS coordinates(I use Kotlin):

```
override fun onSingleTap(v: Float, v1: Float) {
     val center = mapView.toMapPoint(v, v1)
}
```

Then, i use center.x and center.y as lng and lat.

```
if (lat != 0.0) {
        resultBean.setLat(lat);
    }
    if (lng != 0.0) {
        resultBean.setLng(lng);
    }
 tPoiInfoDao.insert(resultBean);
```

Comment: please share the code of function, through which you save the coordinates in database.

Comment: Did you write the code that generates or converts the locations or "points" into GPS coordinates? If so, would it be possible to share that code? Can't see how anyone can help otherwise...

Comment: @Nagev Yes, I  have write the code that Screen coordinates converted to GPS coordinates,use arcgis api.